# React change state in array (for loop)

Tags: reactjs, computed-field, setstate

I have a State with flights, and I have a slider to change the max price to change visibility of the flight elements.

```
maxpriceFilter() {

    var flightOffer = this.state.flightOffer;
    var sliderPrice = this.state.sliderPrice;

    for (var i = 0; i < flightOffer.length; i++) {
        if( flightOffer[i].price > sliderPrice) {   

            this.setState(
                {[flightOffer[i].hiddenprice] : true}
            );
        };
    }
```

This code is adding a undefined field with status true in the root of the state though.. I cant find any best practice on this, other then using computed fields. But I cant get the computed field working either..

Could someone please help me out here?

Comment: Can you share how your state looks like? What I can see is that your state is an array so try using `this.setState({flightOffer[i].hiddenprice : true});`

Comment: @iamsaksham that's actually a feature from ES6 where you define the keys dynamically in the defining object. https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=var%20key%20%3D%20'test'%3B%0Avar%20value%20%3D%20true%3B%0A%0Aconst%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%5Bkey%5D%3A%20value%0A%7D%3B

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't want to do a setState call in a loop, that will have the react component render multiple times. Build a new state object and call the setState once. You also don't want to filter it out by an if statement, but set previous values to hidden:

```
maxpriceFilter() {

    var flightOffer = this.state.flightOffer;
    var sliderPrice = this.state.sliderPrice;
    var newState = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < flightOffer.length; i++) {
        newState[flightOffer[i].hiddenprice] = flightOffer[i].price > sliderPrice;
    }

    this.setState(newState);

    // ...
}
```

If you're still having issues, it could be that the hiddenprice property isn't what you expect? Might need to post your render() function as well.

Comment: Not sure about state being called each time in the loop. Doesn't React merge all setState() calls at the end of the cycle to only call it once ?

Comment: Ah you might be correct. Did a small jsfiddle using a count variable, and it just logged it once. Still, i think calling setState once would be less expensive, but that's getting into more optimization stuff instead of functional :) https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44677/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing your looping when you're updating the state, why not just do the switch on render?

You're probably already looping over all `flightOffers` in `render()`. So, just add the check there. Inside your render, pass `hiddenPrice={offer.price > sliderPrice}` as a prop, or use it directly where you control the visibility.

Why? Because the visibility of a specific item in this case is not state. It is a result of the state.